# Setting CORS via API Gateway for Serverless Architecture Model Proxy Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am working on a C#/.Net serverless application using the AWS Visual Studio Toolkit, and I am having a bit of trouble figuring out what I am missing as far as CORS configuration. I based my project off of the ASP.Net example included with the toolkit, which configured API Gateway to have a single API endpoint that works as a proxy into the ASP.Net Web API framework.

[image]

In testing this application in chrome (serving a local node project) I am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

I know this means I have to configure CORS on the API Gateway endpoint, but I seem to be missing something. I use the actions dropdown to enable CORS as such...

[image]

But I get some errors and the problem persists.

[image]

I used a chrome extension to disable CORS (temporarily) and have confirmed that the API endpoint works normally without CORS.

So what am I missing here? The examples of setting CORS online don't usually have instructions of a catch-all endpoint like this is set up to use, and even breaking `GET` into its own method didn't seem to help.

As an additional question, if there is some CORS configuration I am missing, is there a good way to get it integrated into the `serverless.template` file or some other automated deploy step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with your `ANY` proxy method. As stated here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

> **Note**
>   When applying the above instructions to the ANY method in a proxy integration, any applicable CORS headers will not be set. Instead, you rely on the integration back end to return the applicable CORS headers, such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin

So you will have to make your backend API return the appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think API Gateway will return the CORS headers in the OPTIONS call.  It is for the actual call that your backend needs to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the header on your server as well as the api gateway.
See this sample: - The cors header is applied to the static bucket website

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1178781/Serverless-Architecture-using-Csharp-and-AWS-Amazo

Answer (score 0):

For the APIs to work properly two things must be done:
1. The options method must be correctly setup - usually done using a mock method on the API gateway.
2. The HTTP method implementations in your code must return the CORS header correctly. There are quite a few articles about this if you search.

For me the problem was Point 1; using the API Gateway 'Enable CORS' button did not work for me when I was developing API-Gateway Lambda integration using .NET Core. I also didn't find a way to add creation of the options method in the serverless.template file.

Here's another way to do it; after publishing the lambdas from CLI or VisualStudio, fire a PUT request on the API endpoint and pass a swagger definition which contains the options method defs and ensure you set the query param mode=merge. You can use PostMan to do this.

or

You use a DotNet utility which does the same thing explained here: 
http://sbytestream.pythonanywhere.com/blog/Enabling-APIGateway-CORS
The source code is available on GitHub too.